# Decarboxylation of Sodium Pyruvate

Tags: organic-chemistry

Can Sodium Pyruvate decarboxylate to acetic acid + CO2 in the presence of just moisture and heat?  If so, what kind of temperature is required?

Comment: I would expect acetaldehyde, not acetic acid.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments above, the expected product would be acetaldehyde, not acetic acid.

[image]

If you stop and think about the mechanism of any thermal decarboxylation, you immediately stumble upon the issue. The decarboxylation would lead to a d1 type synthon, which from organic chemistry you should realise is the wrong polarity for a carbonyl group (the natural polarity of the C=O bond is to have a partial positive charge on carbon and partial negative charge on oxygen).

[image]